# question on MD5 state variables

Tags: md5

I am studying MD5 algorithm. I found out that there are four state variables (I am not sure what that means). Those variables are 0x67452301 , 0xEFCDAB89, 0x98BADCFE, and 0x10325476. I converted variables to decimals and came up with 1732584193, 4023233417, 2562383102, and 271733878 resepectively.

my question is, why those numbers? Are they special numbers?

Comment: They sure don't look variable!

Comment: @Grumdrig // Oh....yeah...they don't look like variables. What should I call them? constants? I used 'variables' because...wiki and other documents say they are variables..

Comment: I will point out that they are two pairs of nibble-wise reversals, and that one pair is made up of the low 8 nibbles, and the other of the high 8, each sort of almost in sorted order.

Comment: Just looked at the algorithm. They're constant initializers for the state variables `h0` - `h3`. And I'm going to guess they're sort of arbitrary, tweaked a little by trial and error as the algorithm was designed.

Comment: (So call them "constants" or "initializers" probably.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [RFC 1321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321), section 3.3:

> 3.3 Step 3. Initialize MD Buffer

> A four-word buffer (A,B,C,D) is used to compute the message digest.
> Here each of A, B, C, D is a 32-bit register. These registers are
> initialized to the following values in hexadecimal, low-order bytes
> first):

> ```
>      word A: 01 23 45 67
>      word B: 89 ab cd ef
>      word C: fe dc ba 98
>      word D: 76 54 32 10
> ```

The numbers they picked are just ascending and descending single hexadecimal digits, in order (which *seems* to be a delightfully arbitrary set of initial values).

Since *they* wrote the low-order bytes first, when you write it with the least significant bytes on the *right*, you get 0x67452301, etc.